# How do I change font family in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[Example Fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3XDM.png)

I want to use special fonts in my React Native project.
Sample I downloaded Aleo font and put it in assets/fonts folder.
I want use Aleo font. I've tried this.
box:{fontFamily:'Aleo'} but not working. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the following code in react-native.config.js

for React Native Version ≥ 0.60

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ["./assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
};
```

And running `react-native link` after adding above.

For more detail you can follow this : https://medium.com/@mehrankhandev/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Answer (score 0):

You have to link fonts to android and ios project.

So first create `react-native.config.js` file in root of your project and add this:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: [".assets/fonts/"],
};
```

then run `react-native link` to link fonts to android and ios project.